# Resemblance between bhanga and jhana

Tags: vipassana, samatha

Is there any resemblance between *bhanga* and the *jhanas*? If so, which is the accordance between both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have Priti. In Banga you can see it through out your body where you can see complete dissolution. In Jhana dissolution aspect might not be that clear depending how you gain it.

Comment: Can you gain the dissolution aspect in Jhana from the 1st jhana?

Comment: Yes you can. You have to look at inconsistency of the Jhana factors.